# Retorno [object HTMLInputElement], o que signfica e como resolver?

Tags: javascript

Olá,
Eu quero armazenar no localStorage alguns dados, porém, quando recarrego a página os dados se recuperam de forma bagunçada, mostrando também a informação [object HTMLInputElement]. Você entende onde estou errando?

Aqui um fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9rjLo73z/

Aqui o código, caso preferir:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .mydiv {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .mydiv2 {
        background-color: orange;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="small-container">
    <h1>Dados</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="dado"><br>
        <input id="item2" type="text" placeholder="dado1">
      <input type="button" value="create" onclick="create()">
    </form>

    <h2>Items</h2>
    <section></section>
    <button>Limpar</button>
  </div>


  <script>
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const section = document.querySelector('section');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.getElementById('item');
const input2 = document.getElementById('item2');
let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

const divMaker = (text) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'mydiv')
  div.textContent = text;
  section.appendChild(div);
}
const divMaker2 = (text) => {
  const div2 = document.createElement('div');
  div2.setAttribute('class', 'mydiv2')
  div2.textContent = text;
  section.appendChild(div2);
}

function create() {
  itemsArray.push(input.value);
  itemsArray.push(input2.value);
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
  divMaker(input.value);
  divMaker2(input2.value);
  input.value = "";
  input2.value = "";
};

data.forEach(item => {
  divMaker(item);
  divMaker2(item2);
});

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  localStorage.clear();
  while (section.firstChild) {
    section.removeChild(section.firstChild);
  }
  itemsArray = [];
});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, Thiago, tudo bem?

Seu problema era basicamente esse:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  divMaker(item);
  divMaker2(item2); // este elemento referencia o input de texto, que é renderizado como objeto no HTML
});
```

Basicamente, só de mudar para isso, seu código já deveria funcionar, já que cada funçao basicamente adiciona uma classe, mas o texto ainda precisa ser o elemento `item`:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  divMaker(item);
  divMaker2(item);
});
```

No entanto, fiz uma versão simplificada do seu código, caso queira dar uma olhada e ver como poderia deixá-lo mais enxuto: https://jsfiddle.net/diogocosta/8j9w1qye/15/

Conforme você for ganhando mais experiência, um bom exercício é tentar remover a duplicidade do seu código.

Um abraço!

Comment: Meu caro, muito obrigado! Vou analisar ao máximo teu exemplo pra entender bem a lógica. Abraço!!